# Titanium iOs app and Ti.UI.Window rendering issue

Tags: iphone, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I'm working on an **Appcelerator Titanium** app for **iPhone iOS 6.0**.
There's a `Ti.UI.TabGroup` controller opening this `Ti.UI.Window` that contains a **Gallery** of images.

Everything it's working fine, but just on the first tab opening. In fact when I tap on another tab and then I return in the gallery tab, all images, *except one and I don't know why*, disappear. I verified that `imageViews` objects are still present with their properties, but hidden.

[image]

That's the code for the gallery and imagesView, trying to obtain a "grid" like layout.

```
    var imagesViewsArray = [];
for(var i=0,images=imageAlbums[0].images;i<images.length;i++){
    var element =Ti.UI.createImageView({
        image : images[i],
        width : 100, height: 75, right:5,
    });
    element.addEventListener('singletap',function(e){
        // [cut] Opening modalWindow with fullscreen image
    });
    imagesViewsArray.push(element);
}

var wrapper = Titanium.UI.createView({
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    width:'auto', layout: 'horizontal',
    left: 5,  top: 5,       bottom: 5,
    children: imagesViewsArray
});

var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    style:'vertical', contentWidth:'auto',
    contentHeight:'auto', layout:'vertical',
    width: '100%' , scrollType: 'vertical',
    showVerticalScrollIndicator: true,
    children: [ wrapper ]
});

galleryWin.add( scrollView );
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's a new one for me. "children" is supposed to be [a read-only property](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-property-children). Because you are setting your child views through the array, they aren't being properly added to the parent view or, as you've noticed, retained. They're prematurely going away.

To make this work properly, explicitly .add(eachChildView) to the parent view.

You can further optimize by moving your singletap event listener to the parent view, and then detecting if the evt.source is one of your children (if (evt.source.image) ...).